# converting from pdf to djvu

Tags: linux, pdf, conversion, djvu

How do I convert a PDF book to djvu?

I'm on linux kubuntu 8.04.

Comment: your question is better suited for superuser.com

Answer (score 2):

There is a program called [pdf2djvu](http://code.google.com/p/pdf2djvu/).
Looks like it is [also available in *ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pdf2djvu) (starting with 8.10).

Comment: I have used this and it works fine.